# Functional Programming in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning more about Scala and Spark but have came stuck upon how to structure a function when I am using two tables as an input. My goal is to condense my code and utilise more functions. I am stuck on how I structure the functions when using two tables which I intend to join. My code without a function looks like:

```
 val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.master("local[*]")
.appName("XX1")
.getOrCreate()

val df1 = spark.sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.load("C:/Users/YYY/Documents/YYY.csv")
// df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [customerID: int, StoreID: int, FirstName: string, Surname: string, dateofbirth: int]


val df2 = spark.sqlContext.read
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.load("C:/Users/XXX/Documents/XXX.csv")


df1.printSchema()
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("customerinfo")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("customerorders")


def innerjoinA(df1: DataFrame, df2:Dataframe): Array[String]={
val innerjoindf= df1.join(df2,"customerId")
}

innerjoin().show()
}
```

My question is: how do I properly define the function for innerjoinA (&why?) and how exactly am I able to call it later in the program? And to a greater point, what else could I format as a function in this example?

Comment: What exactly is the question again? Your function should return a **DataFrame** and a `val` assignament returns unit, just remove the `val innerJoinDf =` and leave rest, and correct the return type. Also, **Spark** is more close to **OOP** than to **FP**. Finally why you want to split the code in more functions?

Comment: What I am trying to do is complete the inner join operation within a function. I am not exactly sure which type I should be using so do not go with what I have written. I wish to then print this list, and also use it later in my program as a make queries on the data.

Comment: I am practising using functions as I have more complex code which I would like to encapsulate within a function - making the readability easier.

Comment: What do you mean with complete the join with a function? Also to which list are you referring. Finally for the complex code, you can find for common and repetitive code and abstract all that on methods. For example the reading of both tables can be abstracted to a method that receives the name of the the file to open as an argument.

Comment: So for example: I want to perform the join operation of df1 and df2 with function 'InnerJoin'. Later in my code, I wish to use this join, within another function in which I perform SQL queries on. I am confused as to how to reference 'InnerJoin' with my SQL queries function.

Comment: Do not bother with a function in this case

Comment: On normal **Scala** code just call the function like any other method. `innerJoinA(df1, df2)`. To be able to call it on **SQl**. You need to write an [**UDF**](https://medium.com/future-vision/spark-udfs-we-can-use-them-but-should-we-use-them-2c5a561fde6d) however, note that these have limitations _(like they can not have other `DataFrames` as arguments, thus your join is invalid)_ and they are not recommended due performance implications, it is better to use built-in functions.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Would you recommend to keep the join outside a function in this case and just call it within other functions?

Comment: I would recommend you to read more about Spark. I still do not understand what is your definition of function in this case, and why you want to have just simple join in a **method**. It is not clear what you mean and what you want.

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding here. You understand functional programming doesn't mean wrapping everything in functions right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this.

Create A function to create Spark Session, and **ReadCSV**. This function if you need put into a different file if it's being called by other programs as well.

Just for join, no Need to crate a function. However, you could create to understand the business flow and give it a proper name.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

def getSparkSession(unit: Unit) : SparkSession = {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("XX1")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark
}


def readCSV(filePath: String): DataFrame = {
  val df = getSparkSession().sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load(filePath)
  df
}

def getCustomerDetails(customer: DataFrame, details: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  customer.join(details,"customerId")
}

val xxxDF = readCSV("C:/Users/XXX/Documents/XXX.csv")
val yyyDF = readCSV("C:/Users/XXX/Documents/YYY.csv")
getCustomerDetails(xxxDF, yyyDF).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise on grouping complex tranformations and joins in methods is sound. Only you know if a special innerjoin method makes sense in you usecase.

I usually define them as extension methods so I can chain them one after another.

```
trait/object DataFrameExtensions{
    implicit class JoinDataFrameExtensions(df:DataFrame){
        def innerJoin(df2:DataFrame):DataFrame = df.join(df2, Seq("ColumnName"))
    }
}
```

And then later on in the code import/mixin the methods I want and call them on the DataFrame.

```
originalDataFrame.innerJoin(toBeJoinedDataFrame).show()
```

I prefer extension methods but you can also just declare a method DataFrame => DataFrame and use it in the .transform method already defined on the Dataset API.

```
def innerJoin(df2:DataFrame)(df1:DataFrame):DataFrame = df1.join(df2, Seq("ColumnName"))

val join = innerJoin(tobeJoinedDataFrame) _
originalDataFrame.transform(join).show()
```

Comment: I am not convinced this will be understood.